# What does the divisor in a sprite image mean?

Tags: css

I have a sprite image I am using and have seen other websites that implement a divisor in theirs. I can't figure out what it means. For instance:

```
background: #fff url("/css/sprite.png") no-repeat scroll -107px -55px / 167px padding-box border-box;
```

What does the "167px" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 167px is the background-size.

For full description, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background#Formal_syntax).

But I suggest you to use long-hand syntax for browser compatibility. I have faced some issue with such syntax in safari browser. But using long-hand syntax worked fine:

```
background-position: -107px -55px;
background-size: 167px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite what the forward slash might suggest, it is not a division sign. In fact, it's there to indicate that the two (sets of) numeric values are distinct and unrelated to one another. The "167px" is a value for `background-size`. The `-107px -55px / 167px` portion can be translated to

```
background-position: -107px -55px;
background-size: 167px;
```

The `padding-box` and `border-box` values are for `background-origin` and `background-clip` respectively, although they don't seem necessary in this context since those are their initial values (but I don't know if the surrounding code requires them to be specified here).